# Angular avoid CORS issue from client side

Tags: angular, http, cors

I am trying to get he value from server by using HTTP post in angular but getting the following error

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. Error 403

Is there any possible to change in client side alone instead of server side where i don't have access to change the code

Comment: This has to be handled server side only.

Comment: Actually its your server which is not allowing you to get request because of CORS, so you will have to make changes to your server side API so that it will allow cors request.

Comment: Its a backend issue.

Answer (score 0):

Its a backend issue. It CORS are not allowed, then you cannot do anything about it. That is the whole idea of CORS allowence.

For developement purpose you can simply disable it (in FF for example) using dedicated plugin.